# How to write logs in LaTeX without default indent

Tags: fonts, indentation

The output I want is like the following photo:

[image]

We can see the middle log lines have different font type and indent compared with other plain text.

I have searched a while. The font type seems like courier(texttt{}). But I have no idea about the indent. Anyone has ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `\begin{verbatim}<newline>1.  2011-01-26 ... starting.<newline>\end{verbatim}`? There are other ways, but it seems that people are hesitant to answer since you have provided no code and given only the barest of indications of what you have tried so far. You may find you get better and quicker answers if you edit your question and provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: Welcome home...

Comment: @jon Thanks for your advice! I have read the article and it's inspiring. Your answer works for me. If I only use {verbatim}, could I also control the text type of the text in {verbatim}?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. Perhaps you could look at the [CTAN packages related to verbatim text](https://www.ctan.org/topic/verbatim?lang=en). The package [`fancyvrb`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) is a popular choice, but not the only one.